# UWP AutoGenerateProperty show two collections in DisplayMemberPathCollection

Tags: c#, uwp, auto-generate

I'm trying to modify a comboBox or catalog from showing the property "Name" from a set of collections to show two of them, like "Name" and "Age" for example.

I have already tried to add it as a second parameter as
[DisplayMemberPathCollection("Name","SecondString")]
and modifying the attribute so it takes two parameters.

```
//The autogenerated property in the model:

[AutoGenerateProperty]
[Display("User")]
[PropertyOrder(1)]
[DisplayMemberPathCollection("Name")]
[SelectedItemCollection("SelectedUser")]

//I changed it to this:
[AutoGenerateProperty]
[Display("User")]
[PropertyOrder(1)]
[DisplayMemberPathCollection("Name","Age")]
[SelectedItemCollection("SelectedUser")]

//The attribute modification I made to get two parameters:

public DisplayMemberPathCollectionAttribute(string first = "", string second = "")
{
 DisplayMemberPath = first + second;
}
```

I would like to have those two fields displayed in the combo, but anything just doesn't seem to work and I haven't found anything helpfull yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing was impossible. The [DisplayMemberPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath) doesn't support concatenated field name. The correct way is to create a new field to concatenate the two fields and make the 'DisplayMemberPathCollection' refer to the new field.

For example, you could define a 'FullName' in your model class:

```
public class User:PropertyChangeBase
{
    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }


    private string lastName;

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return lastName; }
        set
        {
            lastName = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string fullName;
    public string FullName
    {
        get { return Name + " " + LastName; }
    }

    private int age;

    public int Age
    {
        get { return age; }
        set
        {
            age = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

}
```

The 'DisplayMemberPathCollection' looks like this: `[DisplayMemberPathCollection("FullName")]`, then the comboBoxItem will show show the full name.